# How to render a component every two iteration in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to `React.js` and very enjoying it, however I've been stuck with a minor issue like below. I'm trying to call `<GridItem>` component every two cycle of iteration of map(). However, it throws `Unxpected token issue on </GridItem>`. I guess it's because the compiler can't see the `<GridItem>` properly. In that case, how do people usually solve the problem? I want to render each two `<Card>` components under every `<GridItem>`.

```
{store.promotion_set.map((promo, index) => {
    <GridContainer>
        {index % 2 === 0 && <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>}
            <Card className={classes.card} key={promo.id}>
                ...
            </Card>
        {index % 2 === 0 && </GridItem>}
    </GridContainer>
})}
```

**UPDATE**

I need to have two `<Card>` components in every `<GridItem>` component, so I thought I need to put if condition on opening and closing components separately. Isn't it possible in React?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, however the way you'r rendering the cards is incorrect. Try this out instead:

```
{store.promotion_set.filter((promo, index) => {
    <GridContainer>
        {index % 2 === 0 && (
         <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>
            <Card className={classes.card} key={promo.id}>
                ...
            </Card>
        </GridItem>
        )}
    </GridContainer>
})}
```

Switching `map` for `filter` allows you to conditionally render the component based on the index value without resulting in any errors due to undefined return statements. In addition, your `{}` runs whatever JS is inside of them, so you only need to run the conditional check in the beginning, without wrapping the component in a check.

Comment: I need to have two `<Card>` components in every `<GridItem>` component, but your way says it renders one `<Card>` in every `<GridItem>`. Can I put if condition on opening and closing components separately?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about your intentions. If you're looking to render every other item in a list and have that item show two cards, you can simply add another card within the GridItem wrapper. However, if your intentions were to conditionally render based on the index, using `map` with an `if / else` statement should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

try the ternary operator:

```
{store.promotion_set.map((promo, index) => {
    <GridContainer>
        {index % 2 === 0 ? <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>
            <Card className={classes.card} key={promo.id}>
                ...
            </Card>
        </GridItem>
        : null
       }
    </GridContainer>
})}
```

**Update** I would possibly move your conditional rendering to something like this:

```
store.promotion_set.map((promo, index) => {
    return index % 2 === 0 ? <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>
            <Card className={classes.card} key={promo.id}>
                ...
            </Card>
            <Card> ... </Card>
        </GridItem>
    </GridContainer> : <GridContainer></GridContainer>
  )
```

Because it seems like you want to conditionally render the entire selection based on the index or just an empty `<GridContainer>`.  I've also added two `Card` components inside the conditionally rendered `GridItem`.

Comment: I need to have two `<Card>` components in every `<GridItem>` component, but your way says it renders one `<Card>` in every `<GridItem>`. Can I put if condition on opening and closing components separately?

Comment: You can't wrap the conditions the way you're doing it, i.e. you can't have a conditional around the opening and closing tag.  Are you looking for something like this: `<GridItem><Card><Card /> <Card><Card /> </GridItem>` -- two cards in each `GridItem` -- or are you trying to limit the number of `GridItem`s?

Comment: If you want to render two `<Card>`s (and that's all you want to do), you can just write `<GridItem><Card><Card /> <Card><Card /> </GridItem>` and two `Card`s will appear under each `GridItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you's want your data structure `promotion_set` array in a set of two such that you'd just need to have two `.map()` methods in the render function:

```
promotion_set = [[card1, card2], [card3, card4]]
```

then you could've rendered it as:

```
promotion_set.map(item => <GridItem>
    {item.map(promo => <Card className={classes.card} key={promo.id}>
     ...
    </Card>)}
</GridItem>)
```

However, if you cannot transform the array in this way, the you could skip over the odd indices while iterating and render two cards:

```
{store.promotion_set.map((promo, index) => {
    <GridContainer>
       {index % 2 === 0 && <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6} key={promo.id}>
           <Card className={classes.card}>
               {store.promotion_set[index].cardText}
           </Card>
           <Card className={classes.card}>
               {store.promotion_set[index+1].cardText}
           </Card>
       </GridItem>
      }
   </GridContainer>
})}
```